# OpenMP with good performance in C function, but not in C++ class method

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have been trying to port a code for an university-related project from C to C++ while also adapting it to an object-oriented paradigm. The original code makes use of OpenMP, through pragmas to create a parallel variation of a function used to calculate certain values and matrices according to an input given by the user.

In C, I wrote a function that returns a struct data type I have defined myself like such. A note: the DoubVet1D/2D functions basically call `calloc` to initialize arrays of a size defined by their argument(s).

```
SaidaEstacionario getDDParallel(DadosEntrada e){
    SaidaEstacionario dd;
    /*
     * Preenche os vetores com os dados do dom�nio
     */
    int J = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < e.numReg; i++)
        J += e.partReg[i];
    int N = e.ordQuad;
    dd.dimFi = J + 1;
    //NNR = e.NNR;
    //double Stop = e.erro;
    //TipoContorno = e.CCETipo + e.CCDTipo;
    double *St = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *Ss = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *Q = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *h = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *S = DoubVet1D(J);
    //double *Fi = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    //double *x = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    //double *TaxaAbR = DoubVet1D(e.numReg);
    double **psiOld = DoubVet2D(e.ordQuad, J + 1);
    double **psi = DoubVet2D(e.ordQuad, J + 1);
    double tmpErro = 0;
    double erro = 0;
    int k = 0;
    dd.fi = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    dd.x = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    dd.x[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < e.numReg; i++)
    {
        double temp = e.tamReg[i] / e.partReg[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < e.partReg[i]; j++)
        {
            h[k] = temp;
            Ss[k] = e.ssZon[e.zonReg[i]];
            St[k] = e.stZon[e.zonReg[i]];
            Q[k] = e.fontReg[i];
            dd.x[k + 1] = dd.x[k] + temp;
            k++;
        }
    }
    /*  Estabelecendo a condi��o de contorno */
    for (int n = 0; n < e.ordQuad/2; n++)
    {
        if(e.cce < 0){
            psi[n][0] = 0;
            psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
        }
        else{
            psi[n][0] = e.cce;
            psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
        }
        if(e.ccd < 0){
            psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][J] = 0;
            psiOld[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0] = psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0];
        }
        else{
            psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][J] = e.ccd;
            psiOld[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0] = psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0];
        }
    }
    /* Obtendo as quadraturas de Gauss-Legendre */
    PLegendre pl = GaussLegendreAbsPes(e.ordQuad);
    double *Mi = pl.mi;
    double *W = pl.w;
    //#############################################
    double start;
    dd.numInter = 0;
    do{
        dd.numInter++;
        /* Calculando a fonte de espalhamento */
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
        {
            S[j] = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                S[j] += 0.25 * Ss[j] * (psi[n][j + 1] + psi[n][j]) * W[n];
        }

        /* Varredura para a direita/esquerda */
#pragma omp sections
        {
#pragma omp section
            {
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        /* Varredura para a direita */
                        psiOld[m][j + 1] = psi[m][j + 1];
                        psi[m][j + 1] = ((Mi[m] / h[j] - 0.5 * St[j]) * psi[m][j] + S[j] + Q[j]) / (Mi[m] / h[j] + 0.5 * St[j]);
                    }
            }
#pragma omp section
            {
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        /* Varredura para a esquerda */
                        psiOld[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j] = psi[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j];
                        psi[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j] = ((Mi[m] / h[J - 1 - j] - 0.5 * St[J - 1 - j]) * psi[m + N / 2][J - j] + S[J - 1 - j] + Q[J - 1 - j]) / (Mi[m] / h[J - 1 - j] + 0.5 * St[J - 1 - j]);
                    }
            }
        } // Aqui h� uma barreira impl�cita


        /*  Estabelecendo a condi��o de contorno */
        if(e.cce < 0 || e.ccd < 0){
#pragma omp parallel for
            for (int n = 0; n < e.ordQuad/2; n++)
            {
                if(e.cce < 0){
                    psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
                    psi[n][0] = psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][ 0];
                }
                if(e.ccd < 0){
                    psiOld[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0] = psi[n][0];
                    psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][J] = psi[n][J];
                }
            }
        }

        /* Calculando o erro para o crit�rio de parada*/
        tmpErro = 0;
        erro = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < N; m++)
            for (int j = 0; j < J; j++){
                tmpErro = Abs(psi[m][j] - psiOld[m][j])/psi[m][j];
                if(tmpErro > erro) erro = tmpErro;
            }
    }while(erro > e.erro);
    dd.tempoVar = omp_get_wtime() - start;
    dd.psi = DoubVet2D(e.ordQuad, J + 1);
    /* Calcula o fluxo escalar */
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j <= J; j++){
        dd.fi[j] = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < N; m++){
            dd.fi[j] += psi[m][j] * W[m];
            dd.psi[m][j] = psi[m][j];
        }
    }
    /*Calcula a taxa de absorção*/
    int i = 0;
    dd.taxaAbsorRegiao = DoubVet1D(e.numReg);
    dd.taxaAbsorTotal = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < e.numReg; r++)
    {
        dd.taxaAbsorRegiao[r] = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = i; j < i + e.partReg[r]; j++)
            dd.taxaAbsorRegiao[r] += 0.5 * (dd.fi[j] + dd.fi[j + 1]);
        dd.taxaAbsorRegiao[r] *= (St[i] - Ss[i]) * h[i];
        dd.taxaAbsorTotal += dd.taxaAbsorRegiao[r];
        i += e.partReg[r];
    }
    return dd;
}
///Execu��o dos c�lculos do m�todo Diamod Difference DD ou Dg estacion�rio vers�o parallel
SaidaEstacionario getDgDDParallel(DadosEntrada e){
    SaidaEstacionario saida;
    /*
     * Preenche os vetores com os dados do dom�nio
     */
    int J = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < e.numReg; i++)
        J += e.partReg[i];
    int N = e.ordQuad;
    saida.dimFi = J + 1;
    //NNR = e.NNR;
    //double Stop = e.erro;
    //TipoContorno = e.CCETipo + e.CCDTipo;
    double *St = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *Ss = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *Q = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *h = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *S = DoubVet1D(J);
    //double *Fi = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    //double *x = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    //double *TaxaAbR = DoubVet1D(e.numReg);
    double **psiOld = DoubVet2D(e.ordQuad, J + 1);
    double **psi = DoubVet2D(e.ordQuad, J + 1);
    double tmpErro = 0;
    double erro = 0;
    int k = 0;
    saida.fi = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    saida.x = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    saida.x[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < e.numReg; i++)
    {
        double temp = e.tamReg[i] / e.partReg[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < e.partReg[i]; j++)
        {
            h[k] = temp;
            Ss[k] = e.ssZon[e.zonReg[i]];
            St[k] = e.stZon[e.zonReg[i]];
            Q[k] = e.fontReg[i];
            saida.x[k + 1] = saida.x[k] + temp;
            k++;
        }
    }
    /*  Estabelecendo a condi��o de contorno */
    for (int n = 0; n < e.ordQuad/2; n++)
    {
        if(e.cce < 0){
            psi[n][0] = 0;
            psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
        }
        else{
            psi[n][0] = e.cce;
            psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
        }
        if(e.ccd < 0){
            psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][J] = 0;
            psiOld[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0] = psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0];
        }
        else{
            psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][J] = e.ccd;
            psiOld[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0] = psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0];
        }
    }
    /* Obtendo as quadraturas de Gauss-Legendre */
    PLegendre pl = GaussLegendreAbsPes(e.ordQuad);
    double *Mi = pl.mi;
    double *W = pl.w;
    //#############################################
    double start;
    start = omp_get_wtime();
    saida.numInter = 0;
    do{
        saida.numInter++;
        /* Calculando a fonte de espalhamento */
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
        {
            S[j] = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                S[j] += 0.25 * Ss[j] * (psi[n][j + 1] + psi[n][j]) * W[n];
        }

        /* Varredura para a direita/esquerda */
#pragma omp sections
        {
#pragma omp section
            {
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        /* Varredura para a direita */
                        psiOld[m][j + 1] = psi[m][j + 1];
                        psi[m][j + 1] = ((Mi[m] / h[j] - 0.5 * St[j] * (1 - e.teta)) * psi[m][j] + S[j] + Q[j]) / (Mi[m] / h[j] + 0.5 * St[j] * (1 + e.teta));
                    }
            }
#pragma omp section
            {
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        /* Varredura para a esquerda */
                        psiOld[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j] = psi[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j];
                        psi[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j] = ((Mi[m] / h[J - 1 - j] - 0.5 * St[J - 1 - j] * (1 - e.teta)) * psi[m + N / 2][J - j] + S[J - 1 - j] + Q[J - 1 - j]) / (Mi[m] / h[J - 1 - j] + 0.5 * St[J - 1 - j] * (1 + e.teta));
                    }
            }
        } // Aqui h� uma barreira impl�cita


        /*  Estabelecendo a condi��o de contorno */
        if(e.cce < 0 || e.ccd < 0){
#pragma omp parallel for
            for (int n = 0; n < e.ordQuad/2; n++)
            {
                if(e.cce < 0){
                    psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
                    psi[n][0] = psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][ 0];
                }
                if(e.ccd < 0){
                    psiOld[e.ordQuad/2 + n][0] = psi[n][0];
                    psi[e.ordQuad/2 + n][J] = psi[n][J];
                }
            }
        }

        /* Calculando o erro para o crit�rio de parada*/
        tmpErro = 0;
        erro = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < N; m++)
            for (int j = 0; j < J; j++){
                tmpErro = Abs(psi[m][j] - psiOld[m][j])/psi[m][j];
                if(tmpErro > erro) erro = tmpErro;
            }
    }while(erro > e.erro);
    saida.tempoVar = omp_get_wtime() - start;
    saida.psi = DoubVet2D(e.ordQuad, J + 1);
    /* Calcula o fluxo escalar */
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j <= J; j++){
        saida.fi[j] = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < N; m++){
            saida.fi[j] += psi[m][j] * W[m];
            saida.psi[m][j] = psi[m][j];
        }
    }
    /*Calcula a taxa de absorção*/
    int i = 0;
    saida.taxaAbsorRegiao = DoubVet1D(e.numReg);
    saida.taxaAbsorTotal = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < e.numReg; r++)
    {
        saida.taxaAbsorRegiao[r] = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = i; j < i + e.partReg[r]; j++)
            saida.taxaAbsorRegiao[r] += 0.5 * (saida.fi[j] + saida.fi[j + 1]);
        saida.taxaAbsorRegiao[r] *= (St[i] - Ss[i]) * h[i];
        saida.taxaAbsorTotal += saida.taxaAbsorRegiao[r];
        i += e.partReg[r];
    }
    return saida;
}
```

As you can see, I only use `#pragma omp parallel for` and `#pragma omp parallel section`. In C++, as part of the object orientation, I transformed the original `SaidaEstacionario` struct in two classes called `Method`and `StationaryMethod` (which inherits from Method), and implemented the function above as a method of a subclass at the lower end of the inheritance, while also encapsulating the variables and creating getters/setters. The end result was a `StationaryMethod`class, which inherits from StationaryMethod, with the following method:

```
void StationaryDD::calculateParallel(){
    /*
     * Preenche os vetores com os dados do dom�nio
     */
    int J = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->inputData.getNumReg(); i++)
        J += this->inputData.getPartReg()[i];
    int N = this->inputData.getQuadOrder();
    this->dimFi = J + 1;
    //NNR = this->inputData.NNR;
    //double Stop = this->inputData.erro;
    //TipoContorno = this->inputData.getCcl()Tipo + this->inputData.getCcr()Tipo;
    double *St = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *Ss = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *Q = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *h = DoubVet1D(J);
    double *S = DoubVet1D(J);
    //double *Fi = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    //double *x = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    //double *TaxaAbR = DoubVet1D(this->inputData.numReg);
    double **psiOld = DoubVet2D(this->inputData.getQuadOrder(), J + 1);
    double **psi = DoubVet2D(this->inputData.getQuadOrder(), J + 1);
    double tmpErro = 0;
    double erro = 0;
    int k = 0;
    this->fi = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    this->x = DoubVet1D(J + 1);
    this->x[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->inputData.getNumReg(); i++)
    {
        double temp = this->inputData.getSizeReg()[i] / this->inputData.getPartReg()[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < this->inputData.getPartReg()[i]; j++)
        {
            h[k] = temp;
            Ss[k] = this->inputData.getSsZon()[this->inputData.getZonReg()[i]];
            St[k] = this->inputData.getStZon()[this->inputData.getZonReg()[i]];
            Q[k] = this->inputData.getSrcReg()[i];
            this->x[k + 1] = this->x[k] + temp;
            k++;
        }
    }
    /*  Estabelecendo a condi��o de contorno */
    for (int n = 0; n < this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2; n++)
    {
        if(this->inputData.getCcl() < 0){
            psi[n][0] = 0;
            psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
        }
        else{
            psi[n][0] = this->inputData.getCcl();
            psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
        }
        if(this->inputData.getCcr() < 0){
            psi[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][J] = 0;
            psiOld[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][0] = psi[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][0];
        }
        else{
            psi[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][J] = this->inputData.getCcr();
            psiOld[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][0] = psi[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][0];
        }
    }
    /* Obtendo as quadraturas de Gauss-Legendre */
    PLegendre pl = PLegendre(this->inputData.getQuadOrder());
    double *Mi = pl.getMi();
    double *W = pl.getW();
    //#############################################
    double start;
    this->numIter = 0;
    do{
        this->numIter++;
        /* Calculando a fonte de espalhamento */
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
        {
            printf("T%d: j = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), j);
            S[j] = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
                S[j] += 0.25 * Ss[j] * (psi[n][j + 1] + psi[n][j]) * W[n];
        }

        /* Varredura para a direita/esquerda */
#pragma omp sections
        {
#pragma omp section
            {
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        /* Varredura para a direita */
                        psiOld[m][j + 1] = psi[m][j + 1];
                        psi[m][j + 1] = ((Mi[m] / h[j] - 0.5 * St[j]) * psi[m][j] + S[j] + Q[j]) / (Mi[m] / h[j] + 0.5 * St[j]);
                    }
            }
#pragma omp section
            {
#pragma omp parallel for
                for (int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
                    {
                        /* Varredura para a esquerda */
                        psiOld[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j] = psi[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j];
                        psi[m + N / 2][J - 1 - j] = ((Mi[m] / h[J - 1 - j] - 0.5 * St[J - 1 - j]) * psi[m + N / 2][J - j] + S[J - 1 - j] + Q[J - 1 - j]) / (Mi[m] / h[J - 1 - j] + 0.5 * St[J - 1 - j]);
                    }
            }
        } // Aqui h� uma barreira impl�cita


        /*  Estabelecendo a condi��o de contorno */
        if(this->inputData.getCcl() < 0 || this->inputData.getCcr() < 0){
#pragma omp parallel for
            for (int n = 0; n < this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2; n++)
            {
                if(this->inputData.getCcl() < 0){
                    psiOld[n][0] = psi[n][0];
                    psi[n][0] = psi[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][ 0];
                }
                if(this->inputData.getCcr() < 0){
                    psiOld[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][0] = psi[n][0];
                    psi[this->inputData.getQuadOrder()/2 + n][J] = psi[n][J];
                }
            }
        }

        /* Calculando o erro para o crit�rio de parada*/
        tmpErro = 0;
        erro = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < N; m++)
            for (int j = 0; j < J; j++){
                tmpErro = fabs(psi[m][j] - psiOld[m][j])/psi[m][j];
                if(tmpErro > erro) erro = tmpErro;
            }
    }while(erro > this->inputData.getE());
    this->tempoVar = omp_get_wtime() - start;
    this->psi = DoubVet2D(this->inputData.getQuadOrder(), J + 1);
    /* Calcula o fluxo escalar */
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j <= J; j++){
        this->fi[j] = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < N; m++){
            this->fi[j] += psi[m][j] * W[m];
            this->psi[m][j] = psi[m][j];
        }
    }
    /*Calcula a taxa de absorção*/
    int i = 0;
    this->taxaAbsorRegiao = DoubVet1D(this->inputData.getNumReg());
    this->taxaAbsorTotal = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < this->inputData.getNumReg(); r++)
    {
        this->taxaAbsorRegiao[r] = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = i; j < i + this->inputData.getPartReg()[r]; j++)
            this->taxaAbsorRegiao[r] += 0.5 * (this->fi[j] + this->fi[j + 1]);
        this->taxaAbsorRegiao[r] *= (St[i] - Ss[i]) * h[i];
        this->taxaAbsorTotal += this->taxaAbsorRegiao[r];
        i += this->inputData.getPartReg()[r];
    }
}
```

Which basically does the same as the function above, but instead of returning the struct data type, simply stores all the data in the object itself defined by the class.

However, when comparing the time spent in each method, **the method implemented in a C++ class takes a LOT more time than the original C function to execute**. It is extremely bad to a point that, where the original C method would result in a fair bit of time saved compared to a non-paralellized variation of the same method (that is, without using OpenMP pragmas), this one will be much worse than it, taking up to a minute to finish a calculation that would be done in a fraction of a second. At first, I thought that the encapsulation could be slowing things down, but simply making everything public and calling the attributes directly instead of getters did not work. Would anyone have any insight as to why this could be happening?

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: You have a `parallel for` inside a `section`. That's pointless: the section gets only one thread. I'd probably get rid of the sections. Next I'd get rid of all the `double*` and `double**`: use `std::vector` throughout.

Comment: Among the most time consuming things there are locking mechanisms and dynamic memory allocation, so I'd check about them. I'm not sure about the advantage of putting *that* in a class method, as it is. Off topic: use abstractions. Modularize the code in smaller functions. Recommended book: "Clean Code" of  Robert C. Martin.

Comment: Your last loop has a statement `i += whatever`. That should be marked as a reduction. I agree with @MatG that most naive omp-ifications suffer from locks and critical section, but I don't see those in the code posted here. In other words: the slowdown is a mystery to me. Make sure that there is no duplicated work: any loop inside an `omp parallel` region should be work-shared.

Comment: Author is asking stackoverflow member to rperform code review provide reason for mismatch in performance.  Stackoverflow should not be used for code review.

Comment: @ABN I'm not asking for "code review" here, I am asking opinions as to why a code in C that works perfectly, when adapted to a method in C++, changing almost nothing except references to the object itself, is suddenly showing a massive loss of performance that isn't present in the original code for nor apparent reason. This is a legitimate doubt, that might have to do with aspects of OpenMP that I am not understanding correctly.

Fortunately, I think I discovered the reason myself (has to do with using the "this" pointer). After confirming it, I will add the solution as an answer to this.

Comment: @MatheusdeOliveira what you could have done is find out execution time at various point in the code and find the time difference. And put the portion of code that is showing massive loss of performance.